# XAMPP with virtualhost is serving the wrong documentroot

Tags: php, apache, xampp, virtualhost

I'm running xampp on Linux and want to set up virtual hosts, so I can quickly jump between projects.

I have two projects set up like this:

`/home/(user)/webdev/app1` which contains an `index.html`

`/home/(user)/webdev/app2` which contains an `index.html`

My `httpd.conf` includes these snippets:

```
<Directory "/home/(user)/webdev/app1">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks ExecCGI Includes
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory "/home/(user)/webdev/app2">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks ExecCGI Includes
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

and `Include etc/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf` is uncommented.

My `httpd-vhosts.conf` includes this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@webdev.app1
    DocumentRoot "/home/(user)/webdev/app1"
    ServerName webdev.app1
    ErrorLog "logs/app1.example.com-error_log"
    CustomLog "logs/app1.example.com-access_log" common
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@webdev.app2
    DocumentRoot "/home/(user)/webdev/app2"
    ServerName webdev.app2
    ErrorLog "logs/app2.example.com-error_log"
    CustomLog "logs/app2.example.com-access_log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

And my `/etc/hosts` file looks like this:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
::1     localhost

127.0.0.1   webdev.app1
127.0.0.1   webdev.app2
```

To my understanding, I did everything right. Unfortunately, when I go to `webev.app1` or `webdev.app2`, it serves the regular `htdocs` folder instead of the modified `DocumentRoot`. When I go to `localhost`, it serves whatever is named first in `httpd-vhost.conf`, in this case `/home/(user)/webdev/app1`.

The behavior I expect would be that app1 is served when I visit webdev.app1 and app2 is served when I visit webdev.app2. What am I missing?

Comment: Do you have any other `<VirtualHost>` block configured in there?  Apache will try to match the requested domain with each `<VirtualHost>`.  If there is no match, it will use the first `<VirtualHost>` block it read from the conf files.

Comment: @Nic3500 No, those are the only two blocks in the file.

Comment: Try this: `apachectl -t -D DUMP_VHOSTS`.  It will show you what VirtualHosts is knows about.  Also, comment out any DocumentRoot directive outside your VirtualHosts.

Comment: @Nic3500 `apachectl -t -D DUMP_VHOSTS` gives this: `*:80                   pop-os.localdomain (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:1)` which looks like it's unaware of my vhosts. I tried commenting the DocumentRoot directive in httpd.conf but it didn't help. Same behavior.

Comment: @Nic3500 Also, when I run systemctl, apache2 isn't in the list at all even when xampp / lampp is running. Maybe that has something to do with it?

Comment: systemctl: it is possible that your installation is not configured into systemctl.  But that is not a problem, systemctl is used mainly to start software at boot time.  Since DUMP_VHOSTS does not indicate your httpd-vhosts.conf, your Include has an error.  Check your directory and path, that is the first thing to figure out.

Comment: @Nic3500 I appreciate you helping out, by the way. The include looks like this: `Include etc/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf` and `httpd-vhosts.conf` is located at `/opt/lampp/etc/extra/httpd-vhost.conf` so that checks out. I tried making that Include path absolute (`/opt/lampp/etc/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf`), but that didn't change anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your virtual hosts are set up incorrectly, you are telling Apache that if any request comes in on port 80 serve app1 and at the same time if any request comes in on port 80 serve app2. Fix it using one of the examples below:

```
----------START DIFFERENTIATE VIA DIFFERENT DOMAINS----------------
 
    Listen 80
    
    <VirtualHost *:80>
        DocumentRoot "/www/app1"
        ServerName www.app1.com
        ServerAlias *.app1.com
    
        # Other directives here
    </VirtualHost>
    
    <VirtualHost *:80>
        DocumentRoot "/www/app2"
        ServerName www.app2.com
        ServerAlias *.app2.com
    
        # Other directives here
    </VirtualHost>

----------END DIFFERENTIATE VIA DIFFERENT DOMAINS----------------


----------START DIFFERENTIATE VIA SUB FOLDERS----------------

    Listen 80

    <VirtualHost *:80>
        DocumentRoot "/www/apps"
        
    
        # in the 'apps' folder place subfolders 'app1' and 'app2'
        # navigate in the browser to each app i.e. 127.0.0.1/apps/app1 and 127.0.0.1/apps/app2
        # Other directives here
    </VirtualHost>

----------END DIFFERENTIATE VIA SUB FOLDERS----------------



----------START DIFFERENTIATE VIA DIFFERENT PORTS----------------

    Listen 81
    Listen 82
    
    <VirtualHost *:81>
        DocumentRoot "/www/app1"
    
        # Other directives here
    </VirtualHost>
    
    <VirtualHost *:82>
        DocumentRoot "/www/app2"
    
        # Other directives here
    </VirtualHost>
    

----------END DIFFERENTIATE VIA DIFFERENT PORTS----------------
```

Comment: Didn't I do the first one? I just didn't add the ServerAlias directive. I added it now but it doesn't help.

Comment: No you didn't do the first one because you specified an invalid ServerName, webdev.app1 is not valid domain

Comment: I see, thank you. It is working now that I added a .com at the end of the ServerName. I had no idea there were rules for the domain name. Thanks again!